# Extracting columns in sets of 3

Tags: matlab, indexing

If I have a matrix that is `16x12 double`, how could I, during each iteration of a loop, extract columns in sets of 3?

e.g. during the first iteration of the loop, columns 1:3 are taken:

```
A= 
    2   3   0   2   3   0   1   3   1   3   0   0
    7   7   1   8   7   0   6   6   0   8   8   1
    4   3   0   3   2   0   3   3   0   3   2   0
    12  12  0   11  10  0   13  14  0   17  10  0
    5   6   0   5   2   0   5   5   0   4   2   0
    3   3   0   4   1   0   4   3   0   2   1   0
    6   14  0   8   11  0   8   9   0   8   5   0
    2   8   0   7   3   0   5   5   0   4   4   0
    4   4   0   3   2   0   5   7   0   5   3   0
    5   6   1   6   4   0   7   2   0   4   8   1
    5   7   1   5   5   0   4   13  0   4   5   0
    8   8   0   8   9   0   8   9   0   10  5   0
    7   9   0   9   6   0   9   8   1   9   4   0
    8   4   1   9   2   0   6   7   1   7   2   0
    11  10  0   8   11  1   9   9   0   11  6   0
    8   10  1   8   10  0   6   11  0   7   9   0
```

i = 1

```
2   3   0
7   7   1
4   3   0
12  12  0
5   6   0
3   3   0
6   14  0
2   8   0
4   4   0
5   6   1
5   7   1
8   8   0
7   9   0
8   4   1
11  10  0
8   10  1
```

i = 2

```
2   3   0
8   7   0
3   2   0
11  10  0
5   2   0
4   1   0
8   11  0
7   3   0
3   2   0
6   4   0
5   5   0
8   9   0
9   6   0
9   2   0
8   11  1
8   10  0
```

And so forth.

I only know how to do this in a convoluted manner, specifying the columns for each iteration i.e.

```
for i=1:size(A,2)/3
    if i == 1
        array = A(:,1:3);
    elseif i == 2
        array = A(:,4:6);
    elseif i == 3
        array = A(:,7:9);
    elseif i == 4
        array = A(:,10:12);
    else
    end
end
```

However this does not allow for accommodation of varying length without altering it every time. Is there a concise manner to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code iterates over the columns of `data` taking `3` columns at a time:

```
data = [2   3   0   2   3   0   1   3   1   3   0   0;
        7   7   1   8   7   0   6   6   0   8   8   1;
        4   3   0   3   2   0   3   3   0   3   2   0;
        12  12  0   11  10  0   13  14  0   17  10  0];

cols = size(data,2);
per_iteration = 3;
for k=1:per_iteration:cols
    selected = data(:,k:(k-1)+per_iteration);
    disp(selected);
end
```

**output**

```
 2     3     0
 7     7     1
 4     3     0
12    12     0

 2     3     0
 8     7     0
 3     2     0
11    10     0

 1     3     1
 6     6     0
 3     3     0
13    14     0

 3     0     0
 8     8     1
 3     2     0
17    10     0
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this.
The simplest, I believe, is to use an iteration variable which increases by three each time.

```
>> A = [2   3   0   2   3   0   1   3   1   3   0   0
7   7   1   8   7   0   6   6   0   8   8   1
4   3   0   3   2   0   3   3   0   3   2   0
12  12  0   11  10  0   13  14  0   17  10  0]
A =

     2     3     0     2     3     0     1     3     1     3     0     0
     7     7     1     8     7     0     6     6     0     8     8     1
     4     3     0     3     2     0     3     3     0     3     2     0
    12    12     0    11    10     0    13    14     0    17    10     0

>> for i=1:3:12
A(:,i:i+2)
end

ans =

     2     3     0
     7     7     1
     4     3     0
    12    12     0


ans =

     2     3     0
     8     7     0
     3     2     0
    11    10     0


ans =

     1     3     1
     6     6     0
     3     3     0
    13    14     0


ans =

     3     0     0
     8     8     1
     3     2     0
    17    10     0
```

A similar method would be to use a variable which increases by one, and pick columns `3*i-2` through `3*i` each time.

A destructive method, which requires no counter, could be to run

```
B = A(:,1:3)
A(:,1:3) = []
```

each itteration. This copies the first three columns to B and then deletes them from A.